# how to return all lines in csv.Dicreader

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm reading a CSV file using `csv.Dicreader`. It returns only the last line as a dict but I want to return all of the lines.

I'm filtering the entire `row` file with dictionary comprehension to get only two `keys:value` using the `field` dict, then doing a little cleanup. I need to return each line as a dict after the cleaning process. Finally, it should return a dict.

```
for row in reader:
    data={value:row[key] for key, value in fields.items()}
    if data['binomialAuthority']=='NULL':
        data['binomialAuthority']=None
    data['label']=re.sub(r'\(.*?\)','',data['label']).strip()

return data
```

out put: 
data= {{'label': 'Argiope', 'binomialAuthority': None}
       {'label': 'Tick', 'binomialAuthority': None}}

Answer (score 1):

Each iteration through the loop, you assign to `data` a single value.  Think of `data` like a small markerboard that only has the last thing you wrote on it.  At the end of the loop it will refer to the last item assigned.

If you just want to print your structure, move the `print` statement into the loop.

If you want a data structure containing multiple dicts, then you need to create a list and then append to it in the loop.  Note that this will use a lot of memory when loading a large file.

eg.

```
my_list = []

for row in reader:
    data = '...'
    my_list.append(data)

return my_list
```

Comment: thank you ... but the above block of code is function for the main code block. i want to return the `data`  as dict with all the line with each line as dict. i don't want to print or append to a list. i cant use the list in mango db to update a file.

Comment: What does the data structure you want look like? If it will be a dict, then what are the keys for the entries in it?

Comment: The data structure i'm looking is dict. the keys are 'binomialAuthority' and 'label'.

Comment: Your description represents only one row from the CSV file.  What structure do you want to contain the dict you described?

Comment: here is what i have. the reader is the variable i assign to `csv.Dicreader`  i'm looping through reader which has a close to 10 key: value  in a single line. i have a another dict `field`  with a just 2 key:value which i used in the dict comprehension to get only the 2 `key:value` i need form the `reader`. but i need to store this each line as dict in a dict like the eg. i have given in my question.

Comment: the data structure i'm look is some thing like this...                                         ```{{'label': 'Argiope', 'binomialAuthority': None} {'label': 'Tick', 'binomialAuthority': None}}```

Comment: That text doesn't look like any standard data structure in python.  If it were a dict you would have a key and a value for each entry.  That looks like a list, or a set, with non-standard string formatting. Eg `print "{%s}" % " ".join(my_list)`

Comment: i'm reading from a csv file  using a csv.Dicreader. so i just i will return me a dict . then i loop it to clean the data. i want my output to loop like a json a dictionary with in dictionary.

Comment: A JSON dictionary (object) is much like a Python dict; both require keys for each entry. What you described, above, is not a JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

the best way is to append it to a list and then use a for loop to unwind the list so that you get a dict type.

```
my_list = []
for row in reader:        
   data = '...'
   my_list.append(data)
for i in my_list:
   print (i)
```